# writing reflective method to load variables from conf file, and assigning references?

Tags: perl, reference, configuration-files

I'm working with ugly code and trying to do a cleanup by moving values in a module into a configuration file.  I want to keep the modules default values if a variable doesn't exist in the conf file, otherwise use the conf file version.  There are lots of variables (too many) in the module so I wanted a helper method to support this.  This is a first refactoring step, I likely will go further to better handle config variables later, but one step at a time.

I want a method that would take a variable in my module and either load the value from conf or set a default.  So something like this (writing this from scratch, so treat it as just pseudocode for now)

```
Our ($var_a, $var_b ...);
export($var_a, $var_b ...);

my %conf = #load config file

load_var(\$var_a, "foo");
load_var(\$var_b, "$var_abar");

sub load_var($$){
   my($variable_ref, $default) = @_

   my $variale_name = Dumper($$variable_ref); #get name of variable

   my $variable_value = $conf{$variable_name} // $default;

   #update original variable by having $variable_ref point to $variable_value
}
```

So two questions here.  First, does anyone know if some functionality like my load_var already exists which I an reuse?

Second, if I have to write it from scratch, can i do it with a perl version older then 5.22?  when I read perlref it refers to setting references as being a new feature in 5.22, but it seems odd that such a basic behavior of references wasn't implemented sooner, so I'm wonder if I'm misunderstanding the document.  Is there a way to pass a variable to my load_var method and ensure it's actually updated?

Comment: `\$var2 = \$var1;` (assigning to a reference in order to the alias two variables) was just added, but `my $ref = \$var; $$ref = $val;` (assigning to a referenced scalar in order to change the scalar) is ancient.

Comment: I would take a slightly different approach: use a data structure to store a reference to each variable, its default value, and the name of the corresponding key in the config hash. Iterate through the structure and assign the appropriate value to the reference. That way the names of your variables don't have to match the keys in the config hash, and you're not doing weird "variable as a variable name" stuff. Something like this: `my %defaults = ( foo => { ref => \$foo, default => "foo" }, ... );` Here, `foo` is a key in the config hash and `$foo` is the variable you want to "load."

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot a good point.  However, there is an order of operations here.  in my example bar is dependent on foo which must be defined first for bar to be defined correctly.  Thus I can't define the "default" key for bar until foo has run.  I don't suppose you know a way to keep a default hash with that requirement?  (though for the record I had figured my load_var subroutine would take an optional argument to overwrite the name of the config file variable.  I prefer to default to things being the same just to speed up the conversion now, while making it not hard coded.

Comment: How do the things that use the module, use the variables? Do they rely on a bulk import e.g. `use GlobalDefs;` to set a whole bunch of things up?

Comment: Sure, that's doable. Use an array so you can iterate in a fixed order and store a reference to the other variable in the "default" field, e.g. `my @defaults = ( { config => 'foo', ref => \$foo, default => "foo" }, { config => 'bar', ref => \$bar, default => \$foo }, ... );` You'll have to check whether the default is a reference or not and handle accordingly.

Comment: Also, keep in mind that this type of thing should only be used as a stop-gap measure to make further refactoring easier. Ultimately you should move away from having a whole bunch of scalars and toward having a single configuration hash. You mention that there are multiple scripts depending on this module; one approach would be to have the bunch of scalars *and* a hash containing the same data. Then you can migrate the scripts over to using the hash one by one, and when none of them use the scalars anymore, remove that from the module.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot can I combine a reference with a string?  defaults=\$foo + "bar" to defer building the string until after foo is set?  I can do it, but the ways I can think of are pretty ugly.  I do agree this is all stop-gap, there are lots of issues with module I want removed.  They have modules building strings based off of other modules variables which in turn are based off of other module variables.  And I want to allow the base variable to be configurable but right now the change won't propagate to the other defined variables.  Lots of things will be changed.

Comment: You could use an anonymous subroutine to construct the default value at run-time, e.g. `sub { $$foo . "bar" }`. You could do lots of other things, too. But this is all getting a little complicated; can you answer @Sobrique's question about how the other scripts are using this module and [edit] an example into your question? There might be a better approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this sort of problem, I would be thinking along the lines of using the [AUTOLOAD](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsub.html#Autoloading) - I know it's not quite what you asked, but it's sort of doing a similar thing:

> If you call a subroutine that is undefined, you would ordinarily get an immediate, fatal error complaining that the subroutine doesn't exist. (Likewise for subroutines being used as methods, when the method doesn't exist in any base class of the class's package.) However, if an AUTOLOAD subroutine is defined in the package or packages used to locate the original subroutine, then that AUTOLOAD subroutine is called with the arguments that would have been passed to the original subroutine.

Something like:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

package Narf;
use Data::Dumper;
use strict;
use warnings;
our $AUTOLOAD;
my %conf = ( fish => 1, 
             carrot => "banana" ); 

sub AUTOLOAD { 
    print "Loading $AUTOLOAD\n";
    ##read config file
    my $target = $AUTOLOAD =~ s/.*:://gr; 
    print $target;
    return $conf{$target} // 0; 
}

sub boo {
    print "Boo!\n";
}
```

You can either call it OO style, or just 'normally' - but bear in mind this creates subs, not variables, so you might need to specify the package (or otherwise 'force' an import/export)

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use Narf;

print Narf::fish(),"\n";
print Narf::carrot(),"\n";
print Narf::somethingelse(),"\n";
print Narf::boo;
```

Note - as these are autoloaded, they're not in the local namespace. Related to variables you've got [this perlmonks discussion](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=372621) but I'm not convinced that's a good line to take, for all the reasons outlined in [Why it's stupid to `use a variable as a variable name'](http://perl.plover.com/varvarname.html)

Comment: a very interesting idea.  I don't think I can use it, the reason I'm keeping the module is because so many others use it; I want to avoid having to touch every variable reference in all the scripts.  Still, a cool concept to know about in the future :)

Comment: Honest question, could you elaborate on why variable names idea is bad?  I read the link but that example doesn't seem to apply (here the problem was they didn't know the variable ahead of time, in my case I'm forcing the config file to be equal a predefined variable not the other way around, I'll know variable names ahead of time so  no increased chance of collision then existed before conf file).  I do see a problem with making it harder to rename variables later which bothers me; but a series of hashes like the link suggests seems as bad for that?  Is there *another* issue I'm missing?

Comment: Thinking about it, I'd be generally less worried in the scenario you outline - because effectively, a module functions as a hash in that it has it's own namespace that you can optionally import. You're already namespacing. (I hadn't finished reading through that PM thread). It still makes me twitch though - IMO the right way to handle it is object based encapsulation rather than bulk import of a bunch of global defs. That's sometimes easier said than done in legacy code though :/

Comment: Thinking further - something like tie might also be relevant http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=15838